# Is an inflatable pool that is more than a few inches off level safe enough to swim in? If not, is it salvageable without dumping?

Tags: pool, leveling

We had this ground “leveled” but apparently not really. It was built up with sand and is already eroding away after a few short weeks. Is it still safe enough to use? Anyone had one of these collapse on them? Can I get through this 4th of July weekend with it? The summer?[image]

Comment: I have only seen a few of those but never seen one collapse just let water out when someone sat on the edge. I would think the bell bottom should keep it in place or slowly let water out.i would lift the tarp and shovel some dirt / sand to make a berm so it won’t roll down the slope. The berm would keep it from moving further.

Comment: What's the worst that could happen? I guess the pool could be destroyed, I don't see much of a safety issue though.

Comment: I had one of these. Also on an angle. It was fine, but I was always there keeping an eye on kids just in case.

Comment: I haven't owned one of these, but it seems that the weight of the water is supposed to push out on the sides to prevent the sag your picture depicts. Have you tried filling it up more?

Comment: If you are swimming laps you will be swimming uphill half the time. ;)